# adding and removing MKAnnotation from a map view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

i have an app where i use MapView and i have 4 types of MKAnnotation. i have also 4 buttons on the screen. each button should show or hide one of the MKannotation types.
i'm able to track the types and remove them.but when i try to add any MKannotation i get an error message. after searching i found a similar problem which has not been answered.

```
An instance 0x6ec5750 of class MapPoint was deallocated while key value observers were    still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached  to some other object.
```

[ios5 removing annotation from a mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597441/ios5-removing-annotation-from-a-mapview)

first of all i'm adding the MKAnnotation from after calling a web service:

```
for (int x=0; x<PromotionsArray.count; x++) 
{
    Promotion *pr = [PromotionsArray objectAtIndex:x];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoord ={ pr.promotionLatitude, pr.promotionLongitude};
    MapPoint *mp= [[MapPoint alloc] initWithCoordinate:newCoord];
    mp.currentTitle=pr.PromotionTitle;
    mp.currentSubTitle=pr.RetailerName;
    mp.currentPromotionArrayID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];
    mp.currentRetailerID = pr.RetailerID;
    mp.currentPromotionType = pr.PromotionType;
    [mapView addAnnotation:mp];
}
```

now i have 4 buttons on the man view. Type1,Type2,Type3 and Type4 button.
if i click on Type1 button it will remove all the MKAnnotation of Type1, using the following code which works perfectly:

```
for (id <MKAnnotation>  myAnnot in [mapView annotations])
    {
        if (![myAnnot isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        {
            if([(MapPoint *)myAnnot currentPromotionType]==PromotionType1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Hiding All Type1 Annotations");
                [mapView removeAnnotation:myAnnot];
            }
        }
    }
```

now if i want to show the Type1 again, i use the following code which cause the problem:

```
    for (int x=0; x<PromotionsArray.count; x++) 
    {
        Promotion *pr = [PromotionsArray objectAtIndex:x];
        if (pr.promotionType==PromotionType1) 
        {
            CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoord ={ [pr.promotionLatitude doubleValue],[pr.promotionLongitude doubleValue]};
            MapPoint *map= [[MapPoint alloc] initWithCoordinate:newCoord];
            map.currentTitle=pr.PromotionTitle;
            map.currentSubTitle=pr.RetailerName;
            map.currentPromotionArrayID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];
            [mapView addAnnotation:map];
        }
    }
```

the problem appears in this line
    [mapView addAnnotation:map];
which causes the error message i mentioned relier(here is it again)

```
An instance 0x6ec5750 of class MapPoint was deallocated while key value observers were    still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached  to some other object.
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Yes, what exactly is the error message and post the code where you add the annotation.  If the error is "deallocated while key value observers were still registered", that might happen because the annotation's coordinates are invalid.

Comment: the error is the same as the one in the link. i've updated the question with the error message.

Comment: Are you releasing MapPoint when you should not be?  Did you add an observer to listen to the button press?

Comment: i'm using ARC and i did not add any observer. the only thing i'm doing to handle the button click is the following: - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control

Comment: You will need to post more code for me to understand the problem.

Comment: anyway, i suggest you to populate an array of MapPoint and then, out of the loop, pass it to the `addAnnotations` (note the plural)

Comment: i tried it and it still not working.

Comment: In the first for-loop, the coordinate is set using `{ pr.promotionLatitude, pr.promotionLongitude}`.  In the third for-loop, coordinate is set using `{ [pr.promotionLatitude doubleValue],[pr.promotionLongitude doubleValue]}` even though `pr` object seems to be same `Promotion` type.  Why is the third for-loop using `doubleValue`?  Can you NSLog the value of newCoord in the third for-loop?

Comment: works now, the problem is in totally another method. i was trying to convert double value to NSString by doing this [Nsstring stringWithFormat:@"%d",doubleVal];  the %d should be %f !!!!! that was a stupid small mistake. thanks all for the help and @AnnaKarenina for your hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works now, the problem is in totally another method.
i was trying to convert double value to NSString by doing this:

```
[Nsstring stringWithFormat:@"%d",doubleVal];
```

the %d should be %f !!!!! that was a stupid small mistake.
thanks all for the help and @AnnaKarenina for your hint

Answer (score 0):

```
// REMOVING ALL ANNOTATION
    for (id <MKAnnotation>  myAnnot in [objMapView annotations])
    {
        if (![myAnnot isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        {
            [objMapView removeAnnotation:myAnnot];
        }
    }
```